# Performance update in Aggregate query

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I would like to improve the performance of the following in aggregate query.

**On T_Search_Detail with 30 million records, below Query takes 12 seconds to execute? can it be written better, suggestions to improve performance?**

Explain Plan:

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 651646209
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                 |     3 |    42 | 27948   (1)| 00:05:36 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY                 |                 |     3 |    42 | 27948   (1)| 00:05:36 |
|   2 |   VIEW                         |                 |    56 |   784 | 27947   (1)| 00:05:36 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY               |                 |    56 |  1344 | 27947   (1)| 00:05:36 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T_SEARCH_DETAIL |   898 | 21552 | 27946   (1)| 00:05:36 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | INDEX_CREATE_DT |  1254K|       |  3451   (1)| 00:00:42 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   4 - filter("TSD"."MATCH_SOURCE" IS NOT NULL AND "TSD"."MATCH_TYPE" IS NOT NULL AND
              "TSD"."MATCH_TYPE" LIKE '%Exact%')
   5 - access("TSD"."CREATE_DT">=TO_DATE(' 2012-12-11 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "TSD"."CREATE_DT"<TO_DATE(' 2013-04-23 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd
              hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Table DDL: 
[image]

This query uses two tables **T_Search** and **T_Search_detail**, with **FOREIGN_KEY** as match_id.

```
SELECT   ms,
         SUM(ct)
FROM     ( SELECT  tsd.match_source    ms,
                  tsd.match_type       mt,
                  COUNT(tsd.search_id) ct
         FROM     t_search ts,
                  t_search_detail tsd
         WHERE    tsd.match_source IS NOT NULL
         AND      tsd.match_type   IS NOT NULL
         AND      ts.match_id                = tsd.match_id
         AND      tsd.match_type          LIKE '%Exact%'
         AND
                  (
                           tsd.create_dt >= to_date('12/11/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                  AND      tsd.create_dt  < (to_date('04/22/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')+1)
                  )
         GROUP BY tsd.match_source,
                  tsd.match_type
         )
GROUP BY ms
ORDER BY ms DESC
```

Comment: You need to provide the explain plan and the table definitions as a minimum otherwise no one will be able to intelligently help you.

Comment: Can you provide some metrics for performance? Time, memory, etc.

Comment: Please also include sizes of tables and information about indexes.

Comment: @Ben I have added those, please check

Comment: @RyanGates Time taken to execute above query is 2.5 seconds, for 194638 records, other details are in execution plan.

Comment: @PM77-1 indexes are on columns, MatchId, create_dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it would be worthwhile to get access to the "%Exact%" rows through an index then you could do so by using a function-based index:

```
create index ... on ... (case Coalesce(InStr(match_type,'Exact'),0) when 0 then null else 1 end)
```

This would include in the index only the rows where the match type contains the string "Exact", and you would query on :

```
where ... and
      (case Coalecse(InStr(match_type,'Exact'),0) when 0 then null else 1 end) = 1
```

You could combine a search on "Exact" with an index on date with:

```
create index ... on ... (case Coalesce(InStr(match_type,'Exact'),0) when 0 then null else create_dt end)
```

... which would index create_dt only for rows where the match_type includes "Exact".

You'd query with:

```
case Coalesce(InStr(match_type,'Exact'),0) when 0 then null else create_dt end >= to_date('12/11/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and
case Coalesce(InStr(match_type,'Exact'),0) when 0 then null else create_dt end  < (to_date('04/22/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need two levels of aggregation for what you are doing.  You can just aggregate by `match_source` and count the number of matching records.

Here is a simplified version of the query, using proper join syntax:

```
SELECT  tsd.match_source ms, COUNT(tsd.search_id) ct
FROM t_search ts join
     t_search_detail tsd
     on ts.match_id = tsd.match_id
WHERE tsd.match_source IS NOT NULL AND
      tsd.match_type   IS NOT NULL AND
      tsd.match_type LIKE '%Exact%' and
      tsd.create_dt >= to_date('12/11/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and
      tsd.create_dt  < (to_date('04/22/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')+1)
GROUP BY tsd.match_source;
```

Next, it looks like the table `t_search` is not being used at all.  It might be used for filtering or it might increase the number of rows.  However, assuming that everything in `t_search_detail` matches exactly one row in `t_search`, then you have:

```
SELECT  tsd.match_source ms, COUNT(tsd.search_id) ct
FROM t_search_detail tsd
WHERE tsd.match_source IS NOT NULL AND
      tsd.match_type   IS NOT NULL AND
      tsd.match_type LIKE '%Exact%' and
      tsd.create_dt >= to_date('12/11/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and
      tsd.create_dt  < (to_date('04/22/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')+1)
GROUP BY tsd.match_source;
```

With this, you might get a performance boost using an index such as `t_search_detail(match_source, match_type, create_dt)`:

```
CREATE INDEX tsearchdetail_matchsource_matchtype_createdt
         ON t_search_detail(match_source, match_type, create_dt);
```

It appears that this query is going to have to do a search through all records that match the date.  Can you expand the list of `match_type` of the form `'%EXACT%'` to a finite list?  If so, then change that line of the `where` to:

```
where . . . and match_type in (<list of exact match types>) . . .
```

Then you want an index on `(match_type, create_dt)`.  However, this will improve performance significantly only if most match types are not "exact" -- You may just be in a position where you have to process lots and lots of records, which might take a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, indexes are already present on these columns, any other thoughts?

Comment: @Narayan . . . The answer is very specific about having one index with the three columns in that order.  Having a separate index on each column will not provide as much benefit.

Comment: why is that so? what makes the order special, please explain

Comment: @Narayan . . . I think the MySQL documentation has a decent explanation of how indexes are used (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  Although there are differences, there are a lot of similarities to how all databases use indexes.

Comment: thanks, i upvoted your answer. but in my QA Environment, with 30 million records, it takes 12-13 seconds to execute, any thoughts?

Comment: I will look into your suggestions on Monday, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: 'Exact type' values are too much, its coming from an external third party call, which is subject to change and not fixed, the only thing constant in literal 'Exact'!

Comment: @Narayan . . . I noticed that you added the `oracle` tag.  Oracle supports functional indexes, so David Aldridge's suggestion should definitely help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the SQL tuning itself, monitor v$sql_workarea_active during the query execution (and v$sql_workarea afterwards) to see whether your query is using temporary tablespace for storage, and if so whether you are incurring a single or multi-pass operations.

Multi-pass operations are a performance killer, and you'd want to make sure you size memory to avoid those, and preferably to avoid single pass operations. To do so you might have to switch your session to manual memory management, or look at the overall allocation of PGA and SGA sizes through their respective cache advisor views.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/memory.htm#i49320